# Замена значения onClick у кнопки при нажатии

Tags: java, android, android-on-click

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки значение `onClick` менялось на другое, т. е. значение `onClick` сначала `sound_on`, а после нажатия `sound_off`, если ещё раз нажать то снова `sound_on`.

activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".supply_system">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/onoff"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="98dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:onClick="sound_on"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/loader"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="57dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="31dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

supply_system:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class supply_system extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageButton btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_supply_system);
    }

   public void sound_on(View view){
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.on);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.onoff);
        ///btn.код для смены
    }

    public void sound_off(View view){
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.off);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.onoff);
        ///btn.код для смены
    }
}
```

Comment: Подскажу фокус(псевдокод), ```public void sound_play_toggle(){if mediaPlayer.isPlay() { sound_off(View view)} else {sound_on(View view)}}``` 

Осталось проверить(найти как это ```mediaPlayer.isPlay()``` правильно записать) (или запомнить например в переменную) воспроизводится ли сейчас звук или остановлен :)

Comment: Привет @ВладимирКлыков, я попробовал ваш код, и не получилось, скорее всего я что-то делаю не так, мне стыдно об этом просить, можете изменить код который я скинул чтобы всё работало

Comment: Так в том-то и дело, что это "псевдокод": он не будет работать в таком виде, зато может подтолкнуть на правильные мысли. StackOverflow — не сообщество по решению задач за Вас. Здесь люди спрашивают совета, а не просят готовое решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задавать onClick через атрибут `android:onClick` в XML-разметке — не очень хорошая практика, это может [неправильно](https://googlesamples.github.io/android-custom-lint-rules/checks/UsingOnClickInXml.md.html) работать на некоторых устройствах.

Заведите поле `isOn`, которое будет отвечать за состояние кнопки и задайте `setOnClickListener` в коде, а не через XML-разметку:

```xml
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/onoff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton button;
    private boolean isOn = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.onoff);
        updateButtonState();
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            isOn = !isOn;
            updateButtonState();
            if (isOn) {
                // проиграть звук включения
            } else {
                // проиграть звук выключения
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateButtonState() {
        button.setImageResource(isOn ? R.drawable.ic_on : R.drawable.ic_off);
    }

    ...

}
```

Не забудьте сохранить состояние активити, чтобы не потерять стейт при пересоздании активити:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("com.example.is_button_on", isOn);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        isOn = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("com.example.is_button_on");
        updateButtonState();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто используйте флаг. Если `true` — то выполнить `sound_off()`, если `false` — то `sound_on()`. В качестве флага можно использовать как состояние `isPlay()`, так и обычную переменную типа `boolean`.